# Inference of union function types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Let's say I have similar architecture to that:

```ts
type GetDog = () => { animal: string; bark: boolean };
const getDog: GetDog = () => ({ animal: 'dog', bark: true });

type GetCat = () => { animal: string; meow: boolean };
const getCat: GetCat = () => ({ animal: 'cat', meow: true });

type AnimalFactory =
  | ((callback: GetDog) => ReturnType<typeof getDog>)
  | ((callback: GetCat) => ReturnType<typeof getCat>);

const calmAnimalFactory: AnimalFactory = (callback) => {
  // Some fancy stuff
  return callback();
};
```

`calmAnimalFactory` as argument should accept `getDog` function or `getCat` function, and then returns corresponding value. The problem is that I guess type inference does not work as I supposed. Callback inside `calmAnimalFactory` doesn't infer type of `GetDog | GetCat`, but instead is `any`. I thought Typescript should determine type of `calmAnimalFactory` in a way that `calmAnimalFactory(getDog)` should be typed as

```ts
((callback: GetDog) => ReturnType<typeof getDog>)
```

and `calmAnimalFactory(getCat)` should be typed as

```ts
((callback: GetCat) => ReturnType<typeof getCat>)
```

I hope it's possible to achieve, but I don't know why it's not working that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things going on here.  First of all, I think if I have to keep typing `typeof getXXX` or `ReturnType<typeof getXXX>`, I will go crazy, so I will define new `Dog` and `Cat` interfaces that correspond to what `getDog()` and `getCat()` return, and use those exclusively:

```
interface Dog extends ReturnType<GetDog> { };
interface Cat extends ReturnType<GetCat> { }
```

You could have and probably should have defined these `Dog` and `Cat` types first and then written `getCat()` and `getDog()` in terms of them:

```
interface Dog {
  animal: string;
  bark: boolean;
}

type GetDog = () => Dog;
const getDog: GetDog = () => ({ animal: 'dog', bark: true });

interface Cat {
  animal: string;
  meow: boolean;
}
type GetCat = () => Cat;
const getCat: GetCat = () => ({ animal: 'cat', meow: true });
```

But either way will work.

---

Next, if you want an `AnimalFactory` to return a `Cat` when you pass it a `GetCat` parameter, *and* you want it to return a `Dog` when you pass it a `GetDog` parameter, then you want to use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types) (`&`) and not a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) (`|`).  If you use a union, you're saying that an animal factory will *either* be something that turns `GetCat` into a `Cat`, *or* it will be something that turns `GetDog` into a `Dog`, but not necessarily both.  So we want the intersection here:

```
type AnimalFactory =
  ((callback: GetDog) => Dog)
  & ((callback: GetCat) => Cat);
```

---

Next, the compiler cannot reason particularly well about whether or not an unannotated and unasserted function implementation conforms to such an intersection of signatures.  Such reasoning would be equivalent to being able to properly type-check [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads), which the compiler simply cannot do (see [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35338#issuecomment-558867975) in [microsoft/TypeScript#35338](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35338) for example).

So if you just try to contextually type the `callback` parameter, the compiler will fail, and end up implicitly using `any`, as you saw.

---

It would be better to use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function implementation that claims to be able to take `callback` of type `() => T` for generic `T extends Cat | Dog`, and then produce a `T`.  That is something the compiler *can* type check:

```
const calmAnimalFactory: AnimalFactory =
  <T extends Cat | Dog>(callback: () => T) => {
    return callback();
  };
```

The compiler is able to verify that a function of type `<T extends Cat | Dog>(callback: () => T) => T` is assignable to both call signatures of `AnimalFactory`, and therefore it compiles with no error.

---

In fact, depending on your use case, you might want to make `AnimalFactory` as universal as possible by removing the dependency on `Cat` and `Dog`, and instead come up with some base type like `Animal`, such as:

```
interface Animal {
  animal: string;
}
type UniversalAnimalFactory = <T extends Animal>(callback: () => T) => T;
const universalAnimalFactory: UniversalAnimalFactory = callback => callback();
```

A `UniversalAnimalFactory` can do anything that an `AnimalFactory` can do (`GetCat` in, `Cat` out; and `GetDog` in, `Dog` out) but it can also do anything else for animals you haven't even thought of yet:

```
const getFish = () => ({ animal: "fish", swim: true });
universalAnimalFactory(getFish).swim // works
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/C4TwDgpgBA4hwBED2BzKBeKAKAlBgfFAN5QCGAdgJYC2pANgFxQDOwATpeSgNxQBGpNgGsmfJEjoQKUAL7cAUAGMk5VlBTxkKJnESoM2POkJYSFGvSYByACaorAGn6CRUdgFdoMnAvmhIsPAAwqTABrgExGRUtIws7Jw8UNQQSADuouKS0nJKKmoawCHAOsGh4UYmZjGWUFaKoY7JqRlubJ6yPvLynMAQbABmpIrQWlAQAB595DbMUABK8O5s5AAq4BAAPLpahCS5vf1DI1DF41MQM3OLwMtrG9tlwHuy3QD0AFQ95H2Dw6P6IjyKDRCxxVgcLgKEECYSZCRScgKGTdfzQHb6TARYxQLQKZSqMKFLSlPRoLGVbDVMHWOwoJqw1weLxdb6-Y7QM5AkHmWJMCGJaHNdLw7JI+QotGBIrlCmRYr4-JEp6ks5ynGmUF8uoNYBNFIitodbwKD5vbqojZQACCNToADFhsAkGwQBhgdgsA06HQBIpXBiUJStDgPQAyT3e33DANPSnFVl5QlQb3UW1gx2KZ2upjp2KZ7Nu9Aezarc7TWancoAH1xqHwXvo0f9TGxhFWlO5IKgbCWKxTTb9QlwQtySbUuoMqbz9ALLpAWEKCfxoQAdLz6KvnQBVMCQNghZgQEfdQ5-E4zujED0b8EJKESvxW7dUABu-WY9Evc9dBlL5cuStLwbKMh1bSkO0iVZFWTdw3w-L87R-EAmBfSh3zYT86G-J15ynQcY0iUCYxPcdlWAe1KGYAALCpIk1W8mAAIgGKjqKYpxmDSGgmGZToFDg9CEOwpDcNdRd4EomicFXLiaCgN43igNIXSEZggA)

Comment: Thank You! This is very helpful response with nice advices :)

Answer (score 2):

You can get proper typing on this using generics.  We say that `calmAnimalFactory` depends on a generic `T` that represents the callback type.  This `T` must be a function that takes zero arguments and returns anything.

Now we can say that the `callback` argument for `calmAnimalFactory` is `T` and the return type of the function is the same as the return type of the callback.

```
const calmAnimalFactory = <T extends () => any>(callback: T): ReturnType<T> => {
  // Some fancy stuff
  return callback();
};

const dog = calmAnimalFactory(getDog); // type: { animal: string; bark: boolean; }
const cat = calmAnimalFactory(getCat); // type { animal: string; meow: boolean; }
```

A slightly different version of the same idea would be to let generic `T` refer to the type of the created animal.  This makes it easier to require that the the callback's return must fit some base `Animal` interface.

```
interface Animal {
  animal: string;
}

const calmAnimalFactory = <T extends Animal>(callback: () => T): T => {
  // Some fancy stuff
  return callback();
};
```

We still get the same types for the `cat` and the `dog`.

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8vbAm)

Comment: Thank You! This also solves my problem :)